# Genymotion not displaying logs in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, genymotion

Android studio does not display my println and Log.d calls as well as errors when I run my application with Genymotion. I have changed the emulator settings so that it uses the same sdk as android studio does. I also made sure to select logcat with my device as target and log level verbose. This problem only occurs with Genymotion, not with the default AVD emulators. I have already tried abd kill-server and adb start-server commands without any success. How could I display the logs from the emulator? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android Studio 1.3, selecting Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration did the job

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the same adb for android studio and genymotion.
In other to do that, use the same Android sdk in both.

Genymotion: Settings > ADB > Browse (to the folder).

Comment: This resolves the issue for me